# Get DateTime from kendo calender in specific format

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used Kendo calender as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // create Calendar from div HTML element
        $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
            format: "yyyy/MM/dd",
            parseFormats: ["MMMM yyyy", "HH:mm"]
        });
    });

    function ShowModal() {
        $('#loading').css("display", "block");
        $('#loading').show();
    }

    function CloseModal() {
        $('#loading').css("display", "none");
        $('#loading').hide();
    }
```

I just wanted to get date out of it on certain javascript function call in the format of:

```
yyyy/MM/dd
```

I tried code as:

```
var calendar = $("#calendar").data("kendoCalendar");
alert(calendar.value());
```

I am passing this value to one of my c# function through ajax.

I am not getting the value in yyyy/MM/dd format.

Value is as follows:

```
Thu Jun 19 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Is there any way by which i can parse this in c# to  yyyy/MM/dd format???

Or is there any way by which i can do it in javascript kendo itself???

Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "value is as follows", exactly? Where are you seeing that value?

Comment: @JonSkeet  on c# function(as i have passed it through ajax) and also through alert i mentioned...alert(calendar.value());

Comment: could you paste the code when passing the value to the server using ajax? kind of $.post??

Comment: i had the same problem, but related to kendo.data.DataSource, I need to send the value as string so it can be parsed by mvc binder kendo.toString(val, "u");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible ways -

1. Format in javascript itself.
2. Format in C#.

From javascript -

```
 var selectedDate = new Date($("#calendar").data("kendoCalendar").value());
 var selectedDateString = selectedDate.getFullYear() + '/' + selectedDate.getMonth() + '/' + 
     electedDate.getDate();    

 alert(selectedDateString);
```

You will get the value in desired format, but you need to send this to C# method as a string.

**From C# -**

Catch the date as DateTime object in C# method parameter (you do not need any change in JS).

So, to example -

```
public void FormatDate(DateTime myDate)
{
   var myDateString = myDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
}
```

Hope this helps.